# How to mount a device in Git Bash?

Tags: git-bash, mount

How do I mount a device in Git Bash ?

#### Versions

```bash
$ git --version
git version 2.18.0.windows.1
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
$ cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

#### Failed attempt

Mount points:

```
$ mount
C:/Program Files/Git on / type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin on /bin type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
C:/Users/bbsop/AppData/Local/Temp on /tmp type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,usertemp)
C: on /c type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
E: on /e type iso9660 (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

Contents of Directory 1 (one file):

```bash
$ ls -al c:/tmp/1
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 1 bbsop 197121 0 Jul 26 22:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 bbsop 197121 0 Jul 26 22:16 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 bbsop 197121 0 Jul 26 22:14 file1
```

Contents of Directory 2 (no files):

```bash
$ ls -al c:/tmp/2
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 1 bbsop 197121 0 Jul 26 22:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 bbsop 197121 0 Jul 26 22:16 ../
```

Attempt to mount `c:/tmp/1` device on `/c/tmp/2`

```
$ mount c:/tmp/1 /c/tmp/2
```

Mount points after mounting `c:/tmp/1` device:

```bash
$ mount
C:/tmp/1 on /c/tmp/2 type ntfs (binary,user)
C:/Program Files/Git on / type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin on /bin type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
C:/Users/bbsop/AppData/Local/Temp on /tmp type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,usertemp)
C: on /c type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

Contents of Directory 2:

```
$ ls -al /c/tmp/2
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 1 bbsop 197121 0 Jul 26 22:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 bbsop 197121 0 Jul 26 22:16 ../
```

**Expected:**

Directory 2 contains "file1".

**Actual:**

Directory 2 is empty.

Comment: What is `c:/tmp/1`? Just a directory? If so, I'm surprised `mount c:/tmp/1 /c/tmp/2` didn't error with `c:/tmp/1 is not a block device`. I guess that's git-bash thing? In any case, does using `mount --bind` work in git-bash?

Comment: @Brian61354270 - Yes, `c:/tmp/1` is just a directory. `mount --bind` gives error `mount: unknown option -- bind`.

Comment: I see, thanks. Sounds like git-bash's `mount` may be different beast from the traditional `mount`. Could you clarify what you end goal is? Does your actual use case involve mounting a block device, and `c:/tmp/1` here is just an example? Or does your actual use case involve mounting an existing directory somewhere else in the filesystem?

Comment: @Brian61354270 I am trying to mount an existing directory somewhere else in the file system (similar to the DOS `subst` command). Based on Git Bash's existing `mount` output I thought user-specified `mount [device] [dir]` commands would work. I am wondering whether it is a bug. There are also other use cases eg. shortening a path, testing different versions of the same application deployed in different C:\ locations against a standard directory eg. "/c/opt/myApp/" etc.

Comment: Generally `mount` is for mounting filesystems on block devices (e.g. hard drive partitions, like `/dev/sdaN`). To alias an existing directory somewhere else in the filesystem, you can use a symbolic link: `ln -s /tmp/1 /tmp/2`